# Changing windows settings with a script

Tags: c#, windows, mousewheel

I have a problem that every once in a while the amount of lines or w\e that moves when I turn the mouse wheel goes from 3 to 30 and my brother sometimes sees it changes to 100.

What I'm talking about is when you go to "Control Panel" -> "Mouse" -> and then the mouse-wheel tab, it has 2 number-scrollers, and I need to change the value of the first one with a script or .exe or whatever way you know how to change it with.

For whoever might encounter that problem and wants the solution, here's the code:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool SystemParametersInfo(int uiAction, int uiParam, IntPtr pvParam, int fWinIni);

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    const int SPI_SETWHEELSCROLLLINES = 0x0069;
    const int SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE = 0x01;
    const int SPIF_SENDCHANGE = 0x02;

    SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETWHEELSCROLLLINES, 3, IntPtr.Zero,
                         SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE | SPIF_SENDCHANGE);
}
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: maybe you could add a tag for the language as well?

Comment: Sure. wasn't totally sure I would have to use C# at first, thought maybe someone would have an easy way using some short .bat file. Will do. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

System parameters are *not* to be changed via registry keys, because (1) that's an implementation detail, that may change in future versions of Windows or even depending on other user profile settings and (2) because you are updating just the saved value, not the one that is currently active.

The correct way to go is to use the `SystemParametersInfo` API specifying the correct parameter constant (in your case, `SPI_SETWHEELSCROLLLINES`) and `SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE | SPIF_SENDCHANGE` as last parameter to both activate it right now and save it for the next sessions.

Comment: Hey man, took me a couple of minutes, but I found all the constant values from pinvoke and it works. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Perhaps there are some WMI objects fir that?

Answer (score 0):

With regedit you can setup a script that sets the mouse wheeel scrolling speed, property is here:
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\WheelScrollLines

just browse regedit (win+R regedit) look at the WeelScrollLines value, then create a reg file as specified by microsoft : https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/310516#bookmark-syntax

Comment: your .reg file will look like that, just two lines in text pad.
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop]
"WheelScrollLines"="3"

Comment: i've edited the post, the registry change works, but the actual value in the control panel does not change